# Inverse kernel of a sine kernel

Tags: integral-transforms, inverse-problems

I’m not a mathematician and I’m working with some transforms in physical chemistry.

I use a transform to pass from the time domain of phase domain in a process that use a square wave to perturb and modulate a stimulus on a system.
In this case, the transform is
$$
A(\phi)= \int_{0}^{T} A(t)\sin(kwt + \phi)\,dt,
$$ where

- $k$ is the frequent of the modulation,
- $w$ is the frequency,
- $t$ is the time and
- $\phi$ is the phase.

After the stimulation and the definition of $A(\phi)$ I want to pass again from the phase domain to the time domain, so to (re)calculate $A(t)$ in the range between $0$ and $2\pi$.
So, what is the inverse kernel of $\sin(kwt + \phi)$? Is it the same?

Just for your information, $k$ can only be a odd integer.

I hope you can help me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Ops, sorry, it is my first time on this website, so thank you for the info!